How to calculate percentile using PERCENT_RANK() using ANSI SQL
I am trying to calculate 25 percentile,75 percentile, 95 percentile and 99 percentile for datasets that have multiple columns, ID-Count, x , y , etc.
I am using Amazon Athena which support Presto SQL.
I have tried this percentile_cont function,
(percentile_cont (.1 ) within group (order by ID_count) over (partition by x, y)) as percentile_10

However it gives me an error of mismatched input 'WITHIN'( I think function is not supported in our database).
Here the code that I am using:
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (partition by x, y order by (ID_count) desc ) as percentile

This code calculate 1,0.83,0.8,0.71,0.7,0.66,0.6,0.57,0.5,0.44,0.428,0.4,0.33,0.3,0.28,0.25,0.22,0.2,0.181.0.166,0.14,0.11,0.1,0.090,0 percentile. I want percent_rank specifically calculate 25, 50,75,90,99 percentile.
I pretty confused what to do , I appreciate any suggestion.

There are several version of ANSI SQL standard. Not sure which one Presto/Trino (Athena is based on them) supports but percentile_cont is not one of the functions supported by the engine. For example recursive queries (added if I'm not mistaken in SQL:1999 were only relatively recently added to Trino )

Sounds like approx_percentile is what you need.
